# Using kotlin 1.8.22 version using command prompt , toUpperCase() and toLowerCase() not working reason

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, kotlin, version

```
fun main()
{
    var txt = "Hello, World!"
    println(txt.toUpperCase())
    println(txt.toLowerCase())
}
```

Error:

```
cd D:\kt
kotlinc Upper_Lower_case.kt
```

Output:

```
Upper_Lower_case.kt:4:13: warning: 'toUpperCase(): String' is deprecated. Use uppercase() instead.
println(txt.toUpperCase())
            ^
Upper_Lower_case.kt:5:13: warning: 'toLowerCase(): String' is deprecated. Use lowercase() instead.
println(txt.toLowerCase())
```

I am using Kotlin version 1.8.22, using the command prompt. toUpperCase() and toLowerCase() are the not working reason.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? Seems like you are only getting a warning - and its message is pretty clear, including the solution (even for someone like me who does not use Kotlin at all!) || BTW not related to the Java Programming Language,  why the [tag:java] tag?

Comment: The Kotlin compiler is telling you to use the Kotlin api instead of the Java api. Both will work fine, but using the Kotlin api is better for compatibility and future proofing.

Comment: Those aren't errors, they are **warnings**.

Answer (score 0):

kotlin 1.8.0

```
fun main() {
        val str = "Hello, World!"
        val upperCaseStr = str.uppercase(Locale.getDefault())
        val lowerCaseStr = str.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
    
        println("Original String: $str")
        println("Uppercase String: $upperCaseStr")
        println("Lowercase String: $lowerCaseStr")
    
        val char = 'a'
        val upperCaseChar = char.uppercaseChar()
        val lowerCaseChar = char.lowercaseChar()
    
        println("Original Char: $char")
        println("Uppercase Char: $upperCaseChar")
        println("Lowercase Char: $lowerCaseChar")
    }
```